# Is this the correct formatting (for grokkability) for this VB.NET code?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, code-formatting

I am not familiar with VB.NET and, in order to try to understand the legacy code (which is sloppily formatted) I'm maintaining better, I fed it into the indentation machine [here](http://www.vbindent.com/?indent).

But this is part of what come out of it:

```
currentYear = Year(Now)
SQLString = "Select NewBiz from MasterUnitsprojSales where CYear = " & currentYear & " and Unit = '" & Unit & "'"
adoRS = New ADODB.Recordset
adoRS.Open(SQLString, adoCon)
IsNewBusiness = TRUE 'default (if record not found)
Category = "New Business"
If Not adoRS.EOF Then
    IsNewBusiness = adoRS.Fields.Item(0).Value <> 0 
    if Not IsNewBusiness
    Category = "Existing Business"
End If
Response.Write("<!-- IsNewBusiness after NOT adoRS.EOF check = " & CStr(IsNewBusiness) & " -->")
End If
adoRS.Close()

If Request.Form.Item("Action") = "Save" Then
Response.Write("<!-- Made it into the Action =Save block -->")
Unit = Request.Form.Item("Unit")
. . .
```

Is this right? It seems to me that it should be more like this:

```
currentYear = Year(Now)
SQLString = "Select NewBiz from MasterUnitsprojSales where CYear = " & currentYear & " and Unit = '" & Unit & "'"
adoRS = New ADODB.Recordset
adoRS.Open(SQLString, adoCon)
IsNewBusiness = TRUE 'default (if record not found)
Category = "New Business"
If Not adoRS.EOF Then
    IsNewBusiness = adoRS.Fields.Item(0).Value <> 0 
    if Not IsNewBusiness
            Category = "Existing Business"
    End If
    Response.Write("<!-- IsNewBusiness after NOT adoRS.EOF check = " & CStr(IsNewBusiness) & " -->")
End If
adoRS.Close()

If Request.Form.Item("Action") = "Save" Then
    Response.Write("<!-- Made it into the Action =Save block -->")
    Unit = Request.Form.Item("Unit")
    . . .
```

I know it's just formatting, and it won't cause the code to work any differently, but it would help me a lot to have it formatted correctly (specifically and especially with the "if"s and "endif"s etc. lining up).

Any time there is an "If" there must be a corresponding "End If" right?

Assuming that's so, this indenterized code is even more confusing:

```
If Not adoRS.EOF Then
CustomerChk = adoRS.Fields.Item(0).Value
adoRS.Close()
If CustomerChk <> CustNo Then
```

...Shouldn't it be:

```
If Not adoRS.EOF Then
    CustomerChk = adoRS.Fields.Item(0).Value
    adoRS.Close()
    If CustomerChk <> CustNo Then
```

? Otherwise, it makes it look like the first if block ends without any explicit say-so.

Comment: Try menu Edit/Advanced/Format Document

Comment: There seems to be an error in the code which is confusing your indentation machine. `if Not IsNewBusiness` should be `If Not IsNewBusiness Then` (notice the `Then` on the end).

Comment: You should never create sql strings like that.  Always use parameters.  It avoids sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: @LarsTech: I know, but my mandate is just to add some new code, not change any existing code. I think the whole thing should be mothballed, but it's not up to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your VB.NET questions...

1) Is this [code indentation updates] right?

It looks OK to me. I probably would insert blank lines before and after the if blocks of code, but that is just my personal preference and not a VB.NET requirement.

2) Any time there is an "If" there must be a corresponding "End If" right?

Usually this is the convention, but this is not a VB.NET requirement. VB.NET allows for single line "If" statements like the following line referenced on this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx).

```
' If A > 10, execute the three colon-separated statements in the order
' that they appear
If A > 10 Then A = A + 1 : B = B + A : C = C + B
```